# Does getting a stack overflow only affect the thread it happened in?

Tags: java

To put it in context :
So lets say I was playing an online game and I created a stack overflow. Would that effect everyone on the server playing as well, or just me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the JVM is on your browser, definitely not.

On the server, a stack overflow will effectively kill the thread.  If it is missing `finally` blocks the thread might die without releasing resources which could wedge the server after a while, but it should release all mutexes held due to `synchonized` blocks.  Assuming the error is not handled, it will call the thead's [`ThreadUncaughtExceptionHandler`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler.html) which normally will not take down the server unless the server is doing work in the main thread, but an uncaught exception handler could be implemented to take down the server.

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how the server is programmed; and what happens with the StackOverflow. If it is not catched it can affect the whole server.

Comment: "If it is not catched it can affect the whole server" this is just incorrect. It will cause the current current thread (that had the stack overflow) to terminate. All other threads continue to run.

Comment: Yeah but if the server waits for an answer from this thread; it can cause problems etc.; if a variable is not set correctly it can affect the wohle server.